Distribute value over rows in a column based on pre-existing value
I am trying to distribute an integer into a column of integers, so that each row end up with values that are as close to each other as possible.
For example, given a table with columns Id and Bin, with pre-existing values:
(1, 3),
(2, 12),
(3, 6)

And @IntegerToDistribute = 7, the result I am imagining is that the row with ID 1 to get 5, and the row with ID 3 to get 2, so that the table would end up with:
(1, 8),
(2, 12),
(3, 8)

And if @IntegerToDistribute = 20, then ID 1 would have gotten 11, ID 3 had gotten 8, and ID 3 had gotten 2, to give the result
(1, 15),
(2, 14),
(3, 14)

Any solutions, or recommendations as how I should approach it?
I could obviously do this very easily as a cursor / while-loop (adding +1 at a time to the row with the smallest Bin value), but that will be very inefficient at bigger sizes of @IntegerToDistribute - so I am looking for a set based solution. (Start of edit) Also preferably avoidable due to code standards in the project I am in. I made a cursor solution previously which I ended up not going for due to this, that looks like this:
WHILE @AmountToAdd > 0 
BEGIN   
   WITH     
   USR  
   (    UserIdMember,       
        PreExistingAmount,
        ToAdd
    ) AS 
    (   SELECT TOP(1)
            USR.UserIdMember,
            USR.PreExistingAmount,
            USR.ToAdd
        FROM
            #Users USR
        ORDER BY
            CH.PreExistingAmount + ToAdd
    )
    UPDATE USR
    SET
        USR.ToAdd= USR.ToAdd+ 1
    FROM
        USR
    WHERE
            1=1 -- condition in CTE;
    SELECT
        @AmountToAdd= @AmountToAdd-1; 
END;

So, the solution is intended to replicate the result from the above, but not be an iterative solution.
(end of edit)
I've tried with NTILE which doesn't seem to really work for this situation, and recursive CTE I cannot really wrap my head around how it would be done for this case.

Why will 20 be split into 11, 8 and 2? Their sum is 21.

It won't be ineffecient until you tried, cursor aren't that bad unless you want to distribute billions of rows which has other issues. Of course, i very much doubt you can write this cursor solution yourself, the question sounds like: "show me teh codez" one

what if you want to distribute a value of 3 but there are 100 rows ?

I guess he wants to top up from the lowest value until it's even with next lowest etc

I've removed my answer as work is pressing so I don't have time, but I've left the fiddle where in case anyone wants to pick it up... https://dbfiddle.uk/51evC9Y5 The problem is in the #adj table if the initial amounts are smaller than the overall target average but bigger the adjusted target bin size.

@siggemannen I did have a solution based on using a WHILE loop, but I didn't find it relevant as it isn't what I am supposed to have or what I am looking for:
BEGIN
 WITH
 USR
 ( UserIdMember,
  PreExistingAmount,
  ToAdd
 ) AS 
 ( SELECT TOP(1)
   USR.UserIdMember,
   USR.PreExistingAmount,
   USR.ToAdd
  FROM
   #Users USR
  ORDER BY 
   CH.PreExistingAmount + ToAdd
 )
 UPDATE USR
 SET 
  USR.ToAdd= USR.ToAdd+ 1
 FROM
  USR
 WHERE 
  1=1 -- condition in CTE;

 SELECT
  @AmountToAdd= @AmountToAdd-1;
END;``` (wow formatting messed up)

@JonasMetzler Ah sorry I got confused when creating the example. IntegerToDistribute should probably be 19, or ID1 should be receiving 10 instead.

Yes, This can be done using set-based logic using the following steps:

Group and count the current bins by their current fill level.
With the results of the prior step ordered by fill level, calculate (a) the cumulative number of bins open at each fill level, (b) the distance difference successive fill levels, (c) the available capacity of each fill level range (bin count * range size), (d) the cumulative capacity across each fill level range.
Select the range that can accommodate the number of items to be added.
Based on the lower limit of that range and the number of bins available in that range, calculate (a) the target full fill level FullFillLevel and the number of residual items ResidualItems that need to be distributed at that full-fill-level + 1.
Select all bins with a current fill level <= the calculated target full fill level and assign them a number RowNum.
Calculate an updated fill level TargetFillLevel for each selected bin as follows: For bins with RowNum <= ResidualItems, the updated value will be FullFillLevel + 1. For all others, the updated value would just be FullFillLevel.
Apply updates for all rows where FillLevel < TargetFillLevel.

Assuming a table structure like:
CREATE TABLE Bins (
    BinId INT,
    FillLevel INT
);

The following stored procedure will update the bin fill levels:
CREATE PROCEDURE AddToBins @NumItems INT
AS

DECLARE @MaxInt INT = 0x7FFFFFFF;  -- Max INT value = 2^32 - 1 (proxy for infinity)

DECLARE @FullFillLevel INT;
DECLARE @ResidualItems INT;

WITH BinCountsByFillLevel AS (
    SELECT
        SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(ORDER BY FillLevel) AS AvailableBins,
        FillLevel
    FROM Bins
    GROUP BY FillLevel
),
FillLevelRanges AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ISNULL(LEAD(FillLevel) OVER(ORDER BY FillLevel), @MaxInt) AS ToFillLevel
    FROM BinCountsByFillLevel
),
FillLevelRangeCapacities AS (
    SELECT
        FLR.*,
        C.RangeCapacity,
        SUM(C.RangeCapacity) OVER(ORDER BY FLR.FillLevel)
            - C.RangeCapacity
            AS FromRangeCapacity,
        SUM(C.RangeCapacity) OVER(ORDER BY FLR.FillLevel)
            AS ToRangeCapacity
    FROM FillLevelRanges FLR
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CAST((FLR.ToFillLevel - FLR.FillLevel) AS BIGINT)
               * FLR.AvailableBins
               AS RangeCapacity
    ) C
),
TargetFillLevel AS (
    SELECT
        FC.*,
        FL.FullFillLevel,
        FL.ResidualItems
    FROM FillLevelRangeCapacities FC
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            (@NumItems - FC.FromRangeCapacity) / FC.AvailableBins + FC.FillLevel
                AS FullFillLevel,
            (@NumItems - FC.FromRangeCapacity) % FC.AvailableBins
                AS ResidualItems
    ) FL
    WHERE FromRangeCapacity < @NumItems
    AND ToRangeCapacity >= @NumItems
)
SELECT @FullFillLevel = FullFillLevel, @ResidualItems = ResidualItems
FROM TargetFillLevel
;

-- Debug print
SELECT @NumItems AS NumItems, @FullFillLevel AS FullFillLevel, @ResidualItems AS ResidualItems;

WITH OrderedBins AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BinId) RN
    FROM Bins
    WHERE FillLevel <= @FullFillLevel
)
UPDATE OB
SET FillLevel = T.TargetFillLevel
FROM OrderedBins OB
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT @FullFillLevel
               + CASE WHEN RN <= @ResidualItems THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               AS TargetFillLevel
) T
WHERE OB.FillLevel < T.TargetFillLevel
;

There may be some ways to consolidate some the above logic, but it works in its current form.
Results (with extra bins and extra test cases):



BinId
InitialFillLevel
+7
+20
+21
+22
+23
+52
+999
+2147483647Max INT value




1
3
8
14
14
15
15
23
181
357913956


2
12
12
14
14
14
15
23
181
357913956


3
6
8
13
14
14
14
23
181
357913956


4
20
20
20
20
20
20
22
181
357913955


5
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
181
357913955


6
20
20
20
20
20
20
22
180
357913955


Total
86
93
106
107
108
109
138
1085
2147483733



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
Another explanation:
Consider an initial condition where we have six bins with fill levels of [3, 12, 6, 20, 25, 20]. This can be visualized as follows:



Fill Range
Bin 1
Bin 2
Bin 3
Bin 4
Bin 5
Bin 6




25 to Inf
.
.
.
.
.
.


20 to 25
.
.
.
.
X
.


12 to 20
.
.
.
X
X
X


6 to 12
.
X
.
X
X
X


3 to 6
.
X
X
X
X
X


0 to 3
X
X
X
X
X
X



Here the X represents the fill and . represents available capacity.
If we reorder the bins by ascending fill level, we can conceptually divide the available capacity into a series of rectangles whose width is the number of available bins at each level and the height is the fill capacity range for that set of bins.



FillRange
Bin1
Bin3
Bin2
Bin4
Bin6
Bin5
AvailableBinCount
RangeSize
RangeCapacity(Rectangle)
CumulativeAvailableCapacity




25 to Inf
<--
---
---
---
---
-->
6
Inf
6 * Inf = Inf
64 to Inf


20 to 25
<--
---
---
---
-->
X
5
5
5 * 5 = 25
39 to 64


12 to 20
<--
---
-->
X
X
X
3
8
3 * 8 = 24
15 to 39


6 to 12
<--
-->
X
X
X
X
2
6
2 * 6 = 12
3 to 15


3 to 6
<->
X
X
X
X
X
1
3
1 * 3 = 3
0 to 3


0 to 3
X
X
X
X
X
X
0
3
0 * 3 = 0
0



(SO table syntax does not support me showing the merged cells above, but consider a horizontal series of <-...-> cells to be merged into a rectangle.)
Now given the number of items to add, we need to pick the row that has a Cumulative Available Capacity that includes that value. All lower ranges will be fully filled and the selected range will be partially filled. It is then a matter of calculating how much to allocate within the selected range. Some bins might receive one more item than the others.
Example 1: If adding 7 items, we will select the 6 to 12 fill level range because 7 falls into the 3 to 15 Cumulative Available Capacity range. If we subtract the lower value of the capacity range 3 from the number of items 7, this leaves is with 4 items to allocate at this level. The number of available bins at this level is 2, so we can allocate 4 / 2 = 2 items each across all two available bins. Adding that to the start of that fill range '6', gives us a new fill level of 8 for those two bins.
Example 2: If adding 20 items, we will select the 12 to 20 fill level range because 20 falls into the 15 to 39 Cumulative Available Capacity range. If we subtract the lower value of the capacity range 15 from the number of items 20, this leaves is with 5 items to allocate at this level. The number of available bins at this level is 3, so we can allocate 5 / 3 = 1 item each across all three available bins with 2 residual items. Adding that to the start of that fill range '12', gives us a new fill level of 13 for those three bins. The 2 residual items increases the fill level to 14 for two of those bins.

This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much for the very clear explanation. I hadn't thought about figuring out a capacity first, I think I ended up being stuck in non-set thinking re: thinking iteration via looping or similar was the only imaginable solution (when I couldn't use CURSOR/ WHILE I still got stuck in thinking it'd had to be a recursive CTE).

Explaning the solution:

I get the value to distribute and start looping

Get minimun actual bin value (top 1) and the next one (LEAD function)

If bin has less than nextbin >> Set the difference between "or" all @Distributed variable value (lowest value)

If bin is equal >> just increment 1

If bin is more than nextbin >> use all @Distributed variable value


After getting the correct distribution, I do:

update/increment the bin value
I get the result as output into table variable (@PartialDistribution)

And finally, I DECREMENT the @Distributed variable with the value that I used
Prepare sample structure and data
DROP TABLE if EXISTS #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Bin INT
);


INSERT INTO #Data (Id, Bin)
VALUES (1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 12);

Start shaping result
DECLARE @PartialDistribution TABLE (
    ID INT,
    BinDifference INT
);

declare @Distributed int = 7

WHILE @Distributed > 0
BEGIN
        DELETE @PartialDistribution

        ;WITH T
        as
        (
                SELECT TOP 1
                       id
                      ,bin
                      ,ISNULL(LEAD(bin,1) over (order by bin),@distributed) as nextBin
                  FROM #Data
              ORDER BY bin
        )
        UPDATE #Data
           SET  bin +=   (CASE WHEN T.bin < nextBin  THEN IIF(nextBin-T.bin <= @distributed,nextBin-T.bin,@distributed)
                               WHEN T.bin = nextBin THEN 1
                               WHEN T.bin > nextBin THEN @distributed
                          END)
                OUTPUT 
                      inserted.ID, 
                      inserted.Bin - deleted.Bin AS BinDifference
                  INTO @PartialDistribution
         FROM #Data d
   INNER JOIN T on T.id = d.id
    
    SET @Distributed -= (select BinDifference from @partialDistribution);
END

and then, the final result
SELECT * FROM #Data

db<>fiddle

if you use 20 as distributevalue, the result is not exact as the op wanted, see this dbfiddle

I suspect the error is in the question, the OP wants to add 20 but the resulting value shown in the question is 43 not 41 (original amount of 21+20). The first (+7) example is fine so I think it's just a typo in the question)

@AlanSchofield You just might be right here

I removed the "previsousBin" column

You should take time to explain the solution here.

Hi Thom, check the explanation and give me a feedback. thanks!

Thank you @FabioAmbrozio! Interesting differences from how I thought to do a looping-solution, where I just updated the lowest bin +1 (through order by) and decreased the value to distribute -1 for each iteration. Something akin to this solution looks a bit more efficient given a looping solution, which unfortunately wasn't was I was looking for. But its cool nonetheless!
